# NIntegrate arguments and non-numerical lists

Tags: list-manipulation, numerical-integration, map

Having two lists

```
 a = {1,2,3}
 b = {4,5,6}
```

and a function

```
   f[lo_, hi_] := NIntegrate[x^2, {x, lo, hi}]
```

I would like to run

```
            Thread[f[a, b]]
```

but I get a

```
  NIntegrate::nlim: x = {0.,1.,2.} is not a valid limit of integration.
```

error.
Why is that?
If I define

```
  f[lo_, hi_] := lo + hi
```

everything works well with Thread, what is the difference?
       f[0, 1]
return $1/3$ as expected, seems a legitimate function with two arguments.

It took me some time but I understood that

```
  f[lo_?NumericQ, hi_?NumericQ] := 
   f[lo, hi] = NIntegrate[x^2, {x, lo, hi}]
```

makes it work, but I am totally confused about the reasons...
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Force NIntegrate not trying evaluating symbolic definition first.

```
f[lo_?NumericQ, hi_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[x^2, {x, lo, hi}] 

Thread[f[a, b]]

(*   {21., 39., 63.}   *)
```

**Edit**
Oh, you meanwhile solved it.

Comment: sorry I was editing just when you were typing, I understood the ?NumericQ bit myself, but yet, why would NIntegrate try symbolically? The documentation says it looks for a numerical integration, what is all about?

Comment: I Don't know exactly either. Seems, when calling f [a,b], the SetDelayed definition is registered with a and b as symbols and at the same time also evaluated, if you don' t prevent this immediate evaluation with a_?NumericQ.